# Why does Janeway go on so many away missions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

As I understand it, Starfleet captains were discouraged from going on away missions. In Star Trek Nemesis, Data cites a specific Starfleet regulation (Section 12, Paragraph 4) on the topic before being cut off by Picard.

**With that in mind, why does Captain Janeway go on so many away missions and why does Chakotay never try to stop her?**

I realize there are occasions where the captain overrides this regulation and goes anyway but one would think these instances would be few and far between like they are in TNG. Janeway seems to jump at the opportunity to get off Voyager every other episode.

Plus, the Delta Quadrant is completely unknown and therefore the potential for unforeseen danger is significantly higher than what Picard saw in TNG.

Comment: Two words: Kirk Syndrome.

Comment: Chakotay was Maquis, so obviously didn't mind a bit of rule breaking?

Comment: Perhaps he's subconsciously hoping she'll die

Comment: The crew on away missions were far more likely to die, and as a sadist, Janeway wanted a front-row seat.  Also, it allowed her to torment *new* people on occasion.

Answer (score 14):

It's brought up multiple times, although not as often as in TNG. Tuvok seems to be the one typically reminding others of regulations but he's also one of those trusting Janeway's judgment the most, especially considering she doesn't throw away all regulations at a whim, even though it might look like that at first.

Overall I always considered the situation similar to ENT: They're understaffed with no way to call in specialists (both distance and partially lack of communication). Janeway might not be an ace pilot like Archer, but she's scientist and seems to be knowing more about different topics than any other member in the crew.

Overall it's just that typical Star Trek trope. The show wants action on the ship and on the ground, but they never want two full leads, so captains often join away teams, meet sexy aliens, etc. with no sane reason.

Comment: And don't forget Chakotay isn't a regular Federation officer - so hasn't had the rules and regs forced down his throat at the academy like most of the people on TNG.

Comment: @RajaniIsa You're right that he isn't a regular Starfleet officer, having spent time in the Maquis. However, he definitely went to the Academy.

Comment: Why does Janeway even **need** to be constantly reminded?

Comment: I'm only partway through Season 2. Are you saying that this policy is brought up by Tuvok at some point?

Comment: @TheIronCheek Wait for seasons three and four. Reminders: It's their job to do. By doing so they avoid repercussions. That's also why Janeway would typically state she noted such statements.

Comment: @RajaniIsa - Chakotay certainly was a 'regular Starfleet officer'.  Yes, he resigned to join the Maquis, but he was an officer (and an Academy instructor) before that.

Comment: You also must consider that a significant amount of what is going on in Voyager revolves around diplomatic and first contact situations.  They do not have a Ship's Conselor, nor do they have a Starfleet Diplomat onboard.